# Spl_autoload_register does not working with external libraries

Tags: php, include, require, spl-autoload-register

I have very simple spl_autoload_register function:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($file) {
    require_once str_replace('\\', '/', $file) . '.php';
});
```

With my classes, everything works fine. I use namespace at the beginning of each class and use it like `$class = new \system\controller\Front();`.

But now, I would like to use this external library/class https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/blob/master/lessc.inc.php. I added namespace as well at the beginning `namespace system\lib\less;` and tried to use method `compileFile()`, but I get error `Warning: require_once(lessc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in`.

What I found is, that first initialization of class `lessc()` is successfull, but the error is on line `no. 2442` - `$commentSingle = lessc::preg_quote(self::$commentSingle);` where the `lessc::` is used.

My `spl_autoload_register` function is not able to handle that, because there is not added the namespace before the name of class, and try to load only `lessc.php` file.

**My question is, how to globally fix it for all other classes/libraries which I would like to add to my project, without editing them (by adding namespaces). Is there any solution how to fix it?**

The only solution I found out, is change my `spl_autoload_register` function to something like this, which seems to work, but I do not know if is it the proper and best solution and I do not know if this will work for all external libraries I would like to use.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($file) {
    // external libraries
    if ($file === 'lessc') $file = 'system/lib/less/lessc';

    require_once str_replace('\\', '/', $file) . '.php';
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I might be inclined to create a json file that would create a location handling record, similar to how composer works. You could make it handle different scenarios based on what the particular library has for it's naming, but there probably won't be a huge range of naming. These days, reputable libraries are pretty good about keeping to best practices when it comes to naming and namespaces:

**/vendor.pref**

```
[
    {
        "name": "lessc",
        "include": "/system/lib/less/lessc.php"
    },
    {
        "name": "other",
        "root": "/system/lib/other",
        "type": "psr0"
    }
]
```

Auto Regsiter

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    # If there is a standard namespace
    $file = str_replace('//','/',__DIR__.'/'.str_replace('\\', '/', $class)) . '.php';
    # Check is file and include
    if(is_file($file)) {
        include_once($file);
        return false;
    }
    # See if there is a vendor file and iterate through it to see if something is set up.
    $json = __DIR__.'/vendor.json';
    if(!is_file($json)) {
        return false;
    }
    # Get the contents and convert to array
    $vendors = json_decode(file_get_contents($json), true);
    # Loop through it
    foreach($vendors as $vendor) {
        # See if the name in the json matches anything in the class
        if(stripos($class, $vendor['name']) !== false) {
            # If there is an include file, try and include it
            if(isset($vendor['include']) && is_file($inc = __DIR__.$vendor['include'])) {
                include_once($inc);
                return false;
            }
            # You can do other autoload options as well that would be 
            # indicated in your json file. You can use other psr types
            # so that you can try replacing _ (instead of \) with /
        }
    }
});
```